# If $A$ and $B$ are sets, and $A$ is element of $B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

If $A$ and $B$ are sets, and $A$ is an element of $B$ does this mean that every element of $A$ is in $B$, or some element of $A$ is in $B$, still makes $A$ element of $B$?

Comment: Do you mean $A$ is subset of $B$?

Comment: No, A and B are sets, and A element of B

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is an element of $B$, then elements in $A$ are not necessarily elements of $B$.

Example: $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{\{1,2\},5\}$. In this case the elements of $B$ are $A=\{1,2\}$ and $5$, but $1$ and $2$ are no elements of $B$.

Comment: You might want to change "elements in $A$ are not elements of $B$" to "elements in $A$ might not be elements of $B$"

Comment: Or maybe use "elements in A are not necessarily elements of B"

Comment: It is wrong:  $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{\{1,2\},1,2\}$

Comment: @JohnMa, Anachor, thanks, I indeed forgot the word "necessarily".

Answer (score 0):

Try to think of some examples: $A = \{1\}$ and $B = \{ A\} = \big\{ \{1\} \big\}$. Then $1$ is not an element of $B$. (Note that $1$ is not the same thing as $\{1\}$)

Comment: great, makes sense

Comment: just look at this question, does this mean that the hypothesis of this incorrect ? 

For all sets A,B,C, if A e B and B e C, then A e C.

Comment: If $A\in B$ and $B\in C$, it's not necessarily true that $A\in C$. Try to construct a counterexample, starting with for example $A = \{1\}$. @SumeetChand  (On the other hand, if $A, B, C$ are sets, $A\subset B$ and $B\subset C$, then it is true that $A\subset C$)

Comment: @SumeetChand Yes, that hypothesis is incorrect. If $C$ is fixed, and that relation holds for all $A$ and $B$, then $C$ is called a _transitive set_, since the $\in$ relation fulfills the property called "transitivity", at least as long as $C$ is at the end of the chain. Not all sets are transitive.

Comment: you guys are great, helped alot